# SQL, SQLite Select from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table 1 Num1 ( Reference table fro 0 to 99 )

Table 2 has Date , Result ( has many records unique by Date and Result)

Table 3 has Result, Num1, Num2, Num3

I would like to Join Table 2 by Result in Table 3
And Match each of Table 1 Num1 to one of the Num1 or Num2 Or Num3 in Table 3
Where the Date is < some Date
Group by Table 1 
so only 100 rows are returned.

How do you get it to stop once if finds the matching 100. It appears to completly scan table 2 everytime. When I get near the end of the table the select goes quicker

Comment: Which is the third table referenced in the title?  What is the name of the column in Table1?  What exactly are you seeking to see?  How the optimizer scans a table is mostly a problem for the optimizer.  Have you got appropriate indexes in place?

Answer (score 0):

Superficially, this might be what you are after:

```
SELECT Num1 AS Num FROM Table2 WHERE Date < '2011-04-12'
UNION
SELECT Num2 AS Num FROM Table2 WHERE Date < '2011-04-12'
UNION
SELECT Num3 AS Num FROM Table2 WHERE Date < '2011-04-12'
```

This selects the unique values from Num1, Num2 and Num3 in Table2.

It is not clear why you need Table1; however, it would be possible to join this result with the values in Table1 to ensure that the values selected appear in Table1.

It is not clear where the third table referred to in the title is, what it contains, or how it might be joined.

If, as I expect, this is missing the point of the question, you need to clarify carefully what you are hoping to see.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of records returned by a SELECT query, you can use the [LIMIT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) clause.

I’ve tried to distill a query that fulfills what I could understand of your query.  But since your explanation was a bit cryptic, chances are I didn’t quite understand what you want:

```
  SELECT Table3.Num1
  ,      Table3.Num2
  ,      Table3.Num3
    FROM Table3
         INNER JOIN Table2
                 ON Table3.Result = Table2.Result
         INNER JOIN Table1
                 ON Table1.Num1 IN (Table3.Num1, Table3.Num2, Table3.Num3)
   WHERE Table2.Date < '2011-04-13'
ORDER BY Table2.Date
   LIMIT 100 -- this will make sure only the first 100 records are returned
  ;
```

If this *does* do what you want, then you should probably consider redesigning your tables.  Having to compare Table1 to all three of Table3.Num1, Num2 and Num3 looks very weird, and more importantly, very inefficient to me.